# Method chaining with Promises

Tags: javascript, node.js, design-patterns, es6-promise

I want to implement the classic method chain pattern, the final usage should be

```
DB
  .push(2)
  .push(3)
```

This is the current code, obviously doesn't work, I'm not clear how to return the reference to DB itself resolving the promise

```
let nodes = [];
let DB = {
    self:this,
    push: (i) => new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        nodes.push(i)
        resolve(this)
    })
}
```

Comment: the real code is way more complex of course

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Only a `class` or `function` instance has a `this` reference.

```js
class DB {
  constructor() {
    this.nodes = [];
    this.promise = Promise.resolve();
  }
  push(i) {
    this.nodes.push(i);
    return this;
  }
  pushAsync(i) {
    return new Promise((resolve) => {
      this.nodes.push(i);
      resolve();
    });
  }
  pushAsyncChain(i) {
    this.promise.then(() => {
      this.promise = new Promise((resolve) => {
        this.nodes.push(i);
        resolve();
      });
    });
    return this;
  }
  then(callback) {
    this.promise.then(callback);
  }
}

const db = new DB();
db.push(2).push(3);
db.pushAsync(4).then(() => db.pushAsync(5));
db
  .pushAsyncChain(6)
  .pushAsyncChain(7)
  .then(() => console.log(db.nodes)); // or await db.promise; console.log(db.nodes);
```

Comment: thanks. Why are you saying I'm not returning a Promise? 

Also, I'm  wondering if there is a way (using async/await) to avoid the use of `then()` outside the class..in order to keep the async usage like  `db.push(2).push(3)`

Comment: `async` can only eliminate `.then` within the function, not outside of it. Your other options include using callback: `db.push(2, db.push(3))`, passing an array: `db.push([2, 3])`, or using await in caller: `await db.pushAsync(2); await db.pushAsync(3)`. Maybe give more details on your actual use case and why the above solutions are problematic?

Comment: your solution is not problematic, it's just not a real method chain. I'll use your `class` solution, thanks

Comment: Just thought of a way to achieve async chaining. See edit. You'll still need to deal with the final promise in the chain in the caller though.

Comment: thanks, your example could be helpful to me even to understand how Promises works in detail.